# Port Forwarding with Sockets and Making Socket Code Public

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, portforwarding

I am trying to allow my code to be run from devices on other networks. The code here is for my server. My question is when going to port forward settings on my router if I want someone to be able to reach the network do I put my external IP or internal IP in the port forward settings? And when I execute the client to try to connect do I give them the external IP and port or internal IP and port to try to connect to?

```
import sockets
def main():
    port = None
    host = str(input("Enter ip to host on:"))
    if host == "port_forward"
        host = "192.xxx.x.x"
        port = 9856
    elif host == "my_ip":
        host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostbyname())
        port = int(input("Enter port to listen to"))
    else:
        port=int(input("Enter port to listen to"))
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))
    print("Host: "+host + " port:"+str(port))
    s.listen(1)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connection from:" +str(addr))
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break
        print("from connected user:")
        data = input("Enter text to send.")
        c.send(data.encode('utf-8'))
    c.close()
main()
```

Comment: You could just say: `host = ""` and your server will listen on **all** interfaces .. (I am not saying this will work for you, I'm just saying this might given the limited info in your question)

Comment: @SuperSaiyan will it work for devices not on my network so that I can send messages to PCs on other networks? And what ip would i log into the client with?

Comment: It will work from where you are able to reach the ip/port. The real answer will depend on your network layout. For eg: are you directly connected to internet, are there any firewall rules, are there port forwarding rules etc. Coming to your main question, you should plan on setting up port forwarding rules like: Ext interface port A => internal ip X + internal port B. You'd connect via external ip and port A

Comment: @SuperSaiyan I think I understand what you mean. Ex set up forwarding so data from the pub addr 78.321.45.41 and port 8888 goes to 192.168.5.27 at port 5555, I have my python code fixed so the host is internal or '' and 5555 but when i go to client with 78.321.45.41 with port 8888 it says connection refused.